# how to mimic search and replace in google apps script for a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace

I wanted to automet some text replacement in a Google sheet.

I utilized the record a macro functionality while doing CTRL-H seacrch and replace, but nothing got recorded.

Then I tryed this code:

```
 spreadsheet.getRange('B:B').replace('oldText','newText');
```

but it does not work, range has no replace method

Should I iterate each cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to replace `oldText` to `newText` for the specific column (in this case, it's the column "B".)
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

Unfortunately, `replace()` cannot be used for the value of `getRange()`. So in this answer, I used TextFinder for achieving your goal.

#### Sample script:

```
var oldText = "oldText";
var newText = "newText";

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(oldText).replaceAllWith(newText);
```

- When you run this script, `oldText` in the column "B" of the active sheet is replaced to `newText`.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [replaceAllWith(replaceText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder.html#replaceallwithreplacetext)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.